# Why can I enter URL directly in adress's bar with hashHistory but not with browserHistory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currenly discover React-Router and I have a question, why can I enter URL directly in adress's bar with hashHistory but not with browserHistory ?

here the url I try to reach :

```
localhost:3000/element/createform
```

here my code :

```
  // import {...}

   // then the code content 
   <ApolloProvider client={client} > 
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={ElementList}/>
            <Route path="element/createform" component={CreateForm} exact/>
          </Route> 
        </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
```

With browserHistory it returns me "cannot get path" but with hashHistory it works. So why ?

Comment: You can change the url manually with `browserHistory`, but because of the nature of the browser it will cause a new request to the server. Could you include the code that gives you this error?

Comment: okay I have edited my code

Comment: Great, that's the URL. Could you include the code, with the `Router`, `Route`, etc.?

Comment: I see, okay, I have edited my topic

Answer (score 0):

You need your web server to always return the main HTML file.

If you call example.com/index.html/test your browser will request example.com/index.html and then let index.html deal eith the hash (at least here).

If you call example.com/index.html/test your browser will request another file called test, which will not be found on the server.